# Values not being added to combobox dynamically

Tags: extjs, dynamic, combobox, addition, store

I have a combobox whose values I need to populate via the json formatted string I am retrieving via AJAX call.

Here's the string which I have retrieved (stored in `data`)

```
{
    "a2m":
    [
        "a2mMeeting",
        "sugar"
    ]
}
```

The combobox must contain `a2m` (this is the only name in the string as of now)

Here's what I have been trying:

**Approach 1:**

```
this.initAjaxCall = Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'indigo/restproxy/get/v1/applications/list',
        method:'GET',
        scope : this,
        success : function(result, request) {
            var data = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
                console.log(key);
                Ext.getCmp('appCombo').getStore().add({appName : key});
            })
        }
});

this.appcombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        id : 'appCombo',
        store: this.appStore
});

this.appStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : [
    {
        name : 'appName',
        type : 'string'
    }
    ]
});
```

**Approach 2:**

```
this.appStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['appName'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'indigo/restproxy/get/v1/applications/list',
            method : 'GET'
        },
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts ) {
                store.insert(0, {
                    'appName' : 'yellow' //Trying to populate randomly using this method.
                })
            }
        }
    })


this.appcombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    id : 'appCombo',
    store: this.appStore
});
```

In both the cases the combobox doesn't load any value and I am unable to see any value in the dropdown menu.

**EDIT 1:** When I printed the store.getCount() in the console after adding one element, the value is shown as 1 (checked by adding two elements and it does show 2). This implies the values are being added to the store but not being shown in the combobox dropdown menu. Kindly suggest how to resolve this.

**SOLUTION:**
The solution as it turns out was by adding a statement queryMode : 'local'. I don't understand why this was creating an issue. Anyone willing to shed light on this is welcome to do so.

Answer (score -1):

As you have proven the store is being populated. However you haven't set a display field on the combo box.

```
this.appcombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    id : 'appCombo',
    store: this.appStore,
    displayField: 'appName'
});
```

> displayField: The underlying data field name to bind to this ComboBox. Defaults to: 'text'
>
> valueField: The underlying data value name to bind to this ComboBox. Defaults to match the value of the displayField config.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alan. I had already added that and tried but again it didn't work. Anyhow the problem is now solved by adding queryMode : 'local'. I don't know why this was creating and issue though

Comment: @aayush_v20 Not sure exactly why it needs queryMode to be set. I don't need to add it with your approach 2 only the first one so I assume it has something to do with the way you are loading data into the store.